# Setting HTML Table rows as dropdowns

Tags: html, css, angular

Im curious about how to configure an HTML table with just a body of rows to be all "dropdowns".
When a user clicks on a row, it will push the rest of the rows down and display a list of similarly named documents. I know how I'll display the contents, but creating that  for the sub-list is what I don't know how to do.

My only thoughts of a solution are creating some  of class "sub-content" and creating the block as such. But even then, I wouldn't know how to do that. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="document-titles">
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let name of dataPackage">
            <tr>
               <td>{{name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS is styled as such:

```
table.document-titles {
  width: 100%;
}

table.document-titles td {
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: medium;
}
```

I did my best to show it in a notepad representation of what I'm looking to do:
[Dropdown Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSLNw.png)

Comment: The `<table>` is quite rigid and may be a poor choice of tag for what you want. Many use nested (un)ordered lists for menu/dropdown stuff. Something like `<ul><li class="toggle">document<li><ul class="subgroup"><li>doc 1<li>doc 2<li>doc 3`. You also might want to have a look at `<detail><summary>`. It has a predefined open/close mechanism.

Comment: That worked out nicely actually! The <details><summary> does pretty much what I needed in the end. Much appreciated Rene!